# Google Sheets: Add URL from one column and wrap it in text (automatically)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of URLs that is created automatically when a Google Form is submitted using the "Add Form Edit Response URLs" script. What I would like to do is copy that link to another sheet and wrap it in text. Like this [EDIT] , but automatically with every link in the column. I know I can do it with `=HYPERLINK("https://urllink", "Edit")`, but I want it to happen automatically down the entire column as new entries are added.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there @HighlandRanger! Unfortunately I can't see your example because the hyperlink is broken, please fix it. Also please share the script/formula that you are using to solve this question.

Comment: OK. Perhaps I am not being clear enough. I have a column that I am showing from one sheet into another by using =QUERY('Data Form'!A1:A, "select *",1). This column has URLS in it. What I want to be able to do is instead of just showing the "raw" URL on the 2nd sheet, I want to have text that looks like this "[EDIT]". I know I can do it manually using =HYPERLINK("https://somelinkhere.com", "[EDIT]", but is there a way to include the HYPERLINK function in the QUERY function to automatically do this on every cell in that column?

Comment: I figured it out: =ArrayFormula(IF(N2:N="","",(hyperlink(N2:N,"EDIT"))))

Comment: I am glad that you solved the issue. Could you please expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: =ArrayFormula(IF(N2:N="","",(hyperlink(N2:N,"EDIT"))))